# I'm having trouble uploading an image with parameters using Alamofire since iOS 9, what's going on?

Tags: swift, ios9, alamofire

My app was uploading fine, the server hasn't changed, nor has the code. But once my phone updated to iOS 9, the headers aren't being properly passed. My server keeps returning unauthorized access since I think the way I attached the header is different than the way I attach the header when a user flags a post.

To clarify: the code did not change, but the software did. I am convinced it is the image upload because there are only two calls with this style of alamofire header due to passing an image with parameters. They both return the same server message of "unauthorized access". This is not a problem with credentials, since the same headers for authorization is passed to writing comments or flagging posts in my api, and they all work fine.

Here is the code for a full image upload:

```
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newAlbumPhoto.originalImage!, 0.20)
    let urlRequest = self.urlRequestWithComponents(Globals.baseURL + "postphotoalbumphotos/" + String(id), parameters: parameters, imageData: imageData!)
    let plainString = "\(user.username!):\(user.encryptedPassword)" as NSString
    let plainData = plainString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let base64String = plainData?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization": "Basic " + base64String!]

    Alamofire.upload(urlRequest.0, data: urlRequest.1)
        .responseJSON { request, response, result in
            switch result {
            case .Success(let JSON):
                completion(results: JSON, error: nil)
            case .Failure(let data, let error):
                if let dataCompletion = data {
                    completion(results: dataCompletion, error: nil)
                }
                if let error = error as ErrorType? {
                    completion(results: nil, error: error)
                }
            }
    }
```

Here is the urlRequestWithComponents method:

```
func urlRequestWithComponents(urlString:String, parameters:Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, imageData:NSData) -> (URLRequestConvertible, NSData) {

    // create url request to send
    let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!)
    mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = Alamofire.Method.POST.rawValue
    let boundaryConstant = "myRandomBoundary12345";
    let contentType = "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundaryConstant
    mutableURLRequest.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    // create upload data to send
    let uploadData = NSMutableData()

    // add image
    uploadData.appendData("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    uploadData.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"file.png\"\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    uploadData.appendData("Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    uploadData.appendData(imageData)

    // add parameters
    for (key, value) in parameters {
        uploadData.appendData("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        uploadData.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n\(value)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    }
    uploadData.appendData("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)--\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

    // return URLRequestConvertible and NSData
    return (Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: nil).0, uploadData)
}
```

And lastly, I should post another snippet of code of mine that makes the same auth header but IS working:

```
let plainString = "\(user.username!):\(user.encryptedPassword)" as NSString
let plainData = plainString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let base64String = plainData?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
let header = ["Authorization": "Basic " + base64String!]

    Alamofire.request(.POST, Globals.baseURL + "flagpost/", parameters: ["user": user.username!, "photoID": id!], headers: header)
        .responseJSON { request, response, result in
            switch result {
            case .Success(let JSON):
                completion(results: JSON, error: nil)
            case .Failure(let data, let error):
                if let dataCompletion = data {
                    completion(results: dataCompletion, error: nil)
                }
                if let error = error as ErrorType? {
                    completion(results: nil, error: error)
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **Alamofire 3.0+**   below  code

```
func uploadImageAndData(){
  //parameters
    let gender    = "M"
    let firstName = "firstName"
    let lastName  = "lastName"
    let dob       = "11-Jan-2000"
    let aboutme   = "aboutme"
    let token     = "token"


    var parameters = [String:AnyObject]()
    parameters = ["gender":gender,"firstName":firstName,"dob":dob,"aboutme":aboutme,"token":token,"lastName":lastName]

    let URL = "http://yourserviceurl/"

let image = UIImage(named: "image.png")

Alamofire.upload(.POST, URL, multipartFormData: {
multipartFormData in
if  let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.6) {
multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: "image", fileName: "file.png", mimeType: "image/png")
}


for (key, value) in parameters {
multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: value.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name: key)
}

}, encodingCompletion: {
encodingResult in

switch encodingResult {
case .Success(let upload, _, _):
    print("s")
        upload.responseJSON { response in
            print(response.request)  // original URL request
            print(response.response) // URL response
            print(response.data)     // server data
            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")
            }
    }

case .Failure(let encodingError):
print(encodingError)
}
})
}
```